# Update JDK on Cloudera Quickstart VM

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I just wanted to have a discussion and get some clarification about a problem I am trying to solve. As of now I have followed this [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cdh_ig_jdk_installation.html) in order to update java on my Cloudera Quickstart VM from Java SE 1.7 to Java SE 1.8. My goal from upgrading to this version is to implement spark 2 on my machine.

After I followed the directions I checked what java version is in the system by typing $ java -version in the terminal. The output though was still the default 1.7 version and not the 1.8 version that the Cloudera manger points to. Why is it that this is happening? Will this discrepancy effect performance at all?

Edit: Change phrasing

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @jgp CentOS 6.10

Comment: You may want to check that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215667/how-to-remove-jdk-7-and-install-jdk-8-in-linux-mint CentOS is an RPM based linux if I am not mistaken, so that would be the way. HIH